# Magento 2 - Is there a way to change element "data-mage-init" without overriding a template?

Tags: magento2, jquery, widget

For example I want to change some options of minicart dialog initialization. So I need to change [minicart template](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml#L30) (override this template in custom theme/module). Is there a way to change minicart dialog init options without overriding a template?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Can you provide more info?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh thanks for replying. I added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "Js Init Modifier" in your custom module.

Your/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block name="js.init.modifier" template="Your_Module::js-init-modifier.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Your/Module/view/frontend/templates/js-init-modifier.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Changes JS component init options before component initialized
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block
 */
?>

<script>
jsInitModifier = {
    BLOCK_TYPE_ATTR: 1,
    BLOCK_TYPE_SCRIPT_TAG: 2,

    /**
     * Changes JS component init options before component initialized
     *
     * @param target String
     * @param options Object
     *
     * @return void
     */
    setJsInitBlockOptions: function (target, options) {
        var initBlocks, initBlock;
        var initBlockType = this.getInitBlockType(target);

        if (initBlockType === this.BLOCK_TYPE_ATTR) {
            initBlock = document.querySelector(target);
        } else if (initBlockType === this.BLOCK_TYPE_SCRIPT_TAG) {
            initBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('[type="text/x-magento-init"]');
            initBlock = this.getInitBlockByKeyword(initBlocks, target);
        }

        if (initBlock === null) {
            console.error('jsInitModifier: cannot find init block "' + target + '"');
            return;
        }

        if (initBlockType === this.BLOCK_TYPE_ATTR) {
            this.setInitBlockOptionsAsAttr(initBlock, options);
        } else if (initBlockType === this.BLOCK_TYPE_SCRIPT_TAG) {
            this.setInitBlockOptionsInScriptTag(initBlock, options);
        }
    },

    /**
     * @param target String
     *
     * @return {Number}
     */
    getInitBlockType: function (target) {
        try {
            var s = document.querySelector(target);

            if (s !== null) {
                return this.BLOCK_TYPE_ATTR;
            } else {
                return this.BLOCK_TYPE_SCRIPT_TAG;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return this.BLOCK_TYPE_SCRIPT_TAG;
        }
    },

    /**
     * @param initBlocks Array
     * @param keyword string
     *
     * @return {Element|null}
     */
    getInitBlockByKeyword: function (initBlocks, keyword) {
        var block = null;

        initBlocks.forEach(function (initBlock) {
            if (initBlock.innerHTML.indexOf(keyword) !== -1) {
                block = initBlock;
            }
        });

        return block;
    },

    /**
     * @param jsonOptionsAsString String
     *
     * @return {Object}
     */
    getInitBlockOptionsObject: function (jsonOptionsAsString) {
        return JSON.parse(jsonOptionsAsString);
    },

    /**
     * @param initBlock Element
     * @param initBlockOptionsCustom Object
     *
     * @return {void}
     */
    setInitBlockOptionsAsAttr: function (initBlock, initBlockOptionsCustom) {
        var initBlockOptionsInitial = this.getInitBlockOptionsObject(initBlock.dataset.mageInit);
        var customInitOptions = this.mergeObjectsRecursive(initBlockOptionsInitial, initBlockOptionsCustom);

        initBlock.dataset.mageInit = JSON.stringify(customInitOptions);
    },

    /**
     * @param initBlock Element
     * @param initBlockOptionsCustom Object
     *
     * @return {void}
     */
    setInitBlockOptionsInScriptTag: function (initBlock, initBlockOptionsCustom) {
        var initBlockOptionsInitial = this.getInitBlockOptionsObject(initBlock.innerHTML);
        var customInitOptions = this.mergeObjectsRecursive(initBlockOptionsInitial, initBlockOptionsCustom);

        initBlock.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(customInitOptions);
    },

    /**
     * Recursively merge properties of two objects
     *
     * @param obj1 Object
     * @param obj2 Object
     *
     * @return {Object}
     */
    mergeObjectsRecursive: function (obj1, obj2) {
        var self = this;

        for (var prop in obj2) {
            try {
                // Property in destination object set; update its value.
                if (obj2[prop].constructor === Object) {
                    obj1[prop] = self.mergeObjectsRecursive(obj1[prop], obj2[prop]);

                } else {
                    obj1[prop] = obj2[prop];
                }
            } catch (e) {
                // Property in destination object not set; create it and set its value.
                obj1[prop] = obj2[prop];
            }
        }

        return obj1;
    }
}
</script>
```

1. Call "setJsInitBlockOptions()" method in you custom template.
2. 1st arg - element selector to change "data-mage-init" attribute **or**
   any text as keyword to change "text/x-magento-init" script content
3. 2nd arg - object with options you want to change. It will be merged with initial options

See example of using the modifier:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var galleryOptions = {
            '[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]': {
                'mage/gallery/gallery': {
                    'options': {
                        'thumbmargin': 15,
                        'thumbborderwidth': 1
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        jsInitModifier.setJsInitBlockOptions('mage/gallery/gallery', galleryOptions);

        var minicartOptions = {
            'dropdownDialog': {
                'triggerEvent': 'hover',
                'closeOnMouseLeave': true,
                'timeout': 0
            }
        };

        jsInitModifier.setJsInitBlockOptions('.block-minicart', minicartOptions);
    })();
</script>
```